# how can I join february '23 with february '22 by day of the week

Tags: php, mysql

Im braking my head of an elegant solution to join feb '23 with feb '22.

With php I'm gettin that the first day of feb '23 as wednesday and the first wednesday of feb '22 was the 2022-02-02, I would like to join them by day of the week to something like this.

```
2023 table:
date        dayoftheweek    people
2023-02-01  Wednesday       4
2023-02-02  Thursday        17
2023-02-03  Friday          4
2023-02-04  Saturday        0
2023-02-05  Sunday          22
2023-02-06  Monday          33
2023-02-07  Tuesday         12
2023-02-08  Wednesday       3
…       
2023-02-28  Tuesday         45



2022 table:
date        dayoftheweek    people
2022-02-01  Tuesday         14
2022-02-02  Wednesday       19
2022-02-03  Thursday        12
2022-02-04  Friday          18
2022-02-05  Saturday        14
2022-02-06  Sunday          19
2022-02-07  Monday          0
2022-02-08  Tuesday         7
2022-02-09  Wednesday       9
…       
2022-02-28  Monday          8


desired result:
date          dayofthweek   2023    2022
2023-02-01  Wednesday       4       19
2023-02-02  Thursday        17      12
2023-02-03  Friday          4       18
2023-02-04  Saturday        0       14
2023-02-05  Sunday          22      19
2023-02-06  Monday          33      0
2023-02-07  Tuesday         12      7
2023-02-08  Wednesday       3       9
…           
2023-02-28  Tuesday     45
```

this is what I came up with and its working fine now:

```
SET @mon_last_year:= 0;
SET @tue_last_year:= 0;
SET @wed_last_year:= 0;
SET @thu_last_year:= 0;
SET @fri_last_year:= 0;
SET @sat_last_year:= 0;
SET @sun_last_year:= 0;

SET @mon_this_year:= 0;
SET @tue_this_year:= 0;
SET @wed_this_year:= 0;
SET @thu_this_year:= 0;
SET @fri_this_year:= 0;
SET @sat_this_year:= 0;
SET @sun_this_year:= 0;


  
  SELECT
  fecha2023,
  day_name_count_this_year,
  fecha2022,
  day_name_count_last_year,
  total_this_year,
  total_last_year
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
    fecha AS 'fecha2023',
    CONCAT(day_name,day_count) AS day_name_count_this_year,
    total AS total_this_year
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
      fecha,
      DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W') AS day_name,
      CASE 
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 1 THEN @sun_this_year:= @sun_this_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 2 THEN @mon_this_year:= @mon_this_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 3 THEN @tue_this_year:= @tue_this_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 4 THEN @wed_this_year:= @wed_this_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 5 THEN @thu_this_year:= @thu_this_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 6 THEN @fri_this_year:= @fri_this_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 7 THEN @sat_this_year:= @sat_this_year+1
      END AS day_count, 
      total
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
        fecha,
        SUM(total_gasto) AS total
        FROM
        gastos
        WHERE
        fecha >= '2023-02-01'
        AND
        fecha <= '2023-02-28'
        GROUP BY fecha
      ) ty_
    ) ty_
  ) ty_

  LEFT JOIN
  
  (
    SELECT
    fecha AS 'fecha2022',
    CONCAT(day_name,day_count) AS day_name_count_last_year,
    total AS total_last_year
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
      fecha,
      DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%W') AS day_name,
      CASE 
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 1 THEN @sun_last_year:= @sun_last_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 2 THEN @mon_last_year:= @mon_last_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 3 THEN @tue_last_year:= @tue_last_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 4 THEN @wed_last_year:= @wed_last_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 5 THEN @thu_last_year:= @thu_last_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 6 THEN @fri_last_year:= @fri_last_year+1
        WHEN DAYOFWEEK(fecha) = 7 THEN @sat_last_year:= @sat_last_year+1
      END AS day_count, 
      total
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
        fecha,
        SUM(total_gasto) AS total
        FROM
        gastos
        WHERE
        fecha >= '2022-02-01'
        AND
        fecha <= '2022-02-28'
        GROUP BY fecha
      ) ly_
    ) ly_
  ) ly_
  ON(day_name_count_this_year = day_name_count_last_year)
```

its returning the desired result really fast but I keep wondering if theres a better way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Is your join supposed to be on date OR type of day?

Comment: There are [not enough details here](/help/how-to-ask) for folks to help: what is the actual data you're working with? What is the ([mcve]) code you already have? (you're asking about mysql, but there is zero sql and no table schema/data in your post).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to PHP?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I didnt explain it well, what I'm trying to do is to compare from the perspective of this month days of the week to the same day of the week of the last year.

So feb '23 first day was wednesday I'm triying to compare it with the first wednesday of feb '22.

sorry my English may be a bit rusty, so the question in my head is "this wednesday we had x people how many we had on the first wednesday of the same month of last year" and so on and so forth, as can be seen in the desired result table, I wish to compare the days of the week in order and not the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "First Friday" of some month will have a `DAYOFMONTH(date) % 7 = 0`.

So

```
SELECT ...
FROM fecha2022
JOIN fecha2023
   ON DAYOFWEEK(fecha2023.data)
    = DAYOFWEEK(fecha2022.data)
  AND DAYOFMONTH(fecha2023.data) MOD 7
    = DAYOFMONTH(fecha2022.data) MOD 7
WHERE ...
```

No need for any CASE expression.